# Django model to record transactions from two different apps of a Bookstore website

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django and i'd like to build a bookstore. The site will sell 2 types of products (Books and Individual question solutions) and i have split those into 2 different django apps. How can i handle the final individual purchases. Is there a way to for example have 1 'Purchase' model that will recieve either Books or Solutions and save transaction into database upon completion of purchase ? 
I want this Purchase model to have title, date of purchase, customer info (name and email).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you are very flexibel when using Django.Models. Since one/many-to-many fields can "link information" behind the scenes, there are close to no limits.

You may start with this model structure in your app:

```
from django.db import models

# Basic Books Model

class BooksPurchase(models.Model):
    books_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    books_purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    books_customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    books_customer_email = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'books_purchase'


# Basic Solutions Model

class Solutions(models.Model):
    solutions_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    [...]

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'solutions_information'

# Basic User Model

class Customers(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    customer_mail = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    [...]

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customer_data'
```

Note that you can use any Model within any file of your Django project by just importing it:

```
from app.models import model_name
```

Also don't forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` to push the model to the DB.

Comment: what i'd actually want to do is have 1 central app to handle things like purchases and marketing. As for purchases, i want a Purchase model that will handle orders from both Books and Solutions apps. In the database, the model will have customer_name, title of book/solution etc, and one more field that is going to specify whether the order was a Books or Solutions instance.

Comment: ye no worries, just go for it. I slightly adjusted my answer to give you a kick-start.